# How to improve speed of query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have got next table with data:

```
CREATE TABLE xml_files ( 
    "parsing_status" Character Varying( 150 ),
    "purchaseNumber" Character Varying( 2044 ),
    "docPublishDate" Timestamp With Time Zone );
 ;
```

data:

```
purchaseNumber  parsing_status  docPublishDate
0373200554017000226 null    2017-07-28 19:00:10.885+03
0373200554017000226 null    2017-07-28 19:08:30.346+03
0373200554017000226 null    2017-07-28 19:24:35.265+03
0373400005317002182 null    2017-07-28 19:45:02.162+03
0348100035117000082 null    2017-07-28 20:08:26.37+03
0373200554017000292 null    2017-07-28 20:10:24.312+03
0373200081217000531 null    2017-07-28 20:13:56.166+03
0373200041517000400 null    2017-07-28 21:23:20.616+03
0373200081217000531 null    2017-07-29 08:18:29.571+03
0373200081217000531 null    2017-07-29 09:34:11.545+03
0373100026117000078 null    2017-07-29 10:37:01.161+03
0573400000117001086 null    2017-07-29 11:25:37.863+03
0573400000117001096 null    2017-07-29 11:30:36.499+03
0373200081217000531 null    2017-07-29 12:14:04.033+03
0573400000117001118 null    2017-07-29 14:50:34+03
0573400000117001118 null    2017-07-29 16:49:12.457+03
0373100026117000080 null    2017-07-29 16:52:02.013+03
0373100026117000080 null    2017-07-29 17:05:40.981+03
0373100026117000080 null    2017-07-29 17:13:29.532+03
0373200554017000226 null    2017-07-29 18:55:47.488+03
```

The column `purchaseNumber` have duplicates.
I need to select for processing all latest unparsed records. I am doing it with next SQL:

```
 SELECT
 "purchaseNumber", "parsing_status", "docPublishDate"
  FROM (
    select distinct on ("purchaseNumber") x.*
    from xml_files x
    order by "purchaseNumber", "docPublishDate" desc
  ) x
  where parsing_status is distinct from 'true'
     AND parsing_status IS NULL 
   order by "docPublishDate" LIMIT 100
```

The problem that query is take very long time on table with millions for rows.
How I can improve speed?
Here is data sample: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vycMHGLYML5K56SN77HLsY/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your query, you want an index on `xml_files("purchaseNumber", "docPublishDate" desc)`:

```
create index idx_xml_files_2 on xml_files("purchaseNumber", "docPublishDate" desc)
```

Postgres should use this index for the `order by`, which facilitates the `distinct on`.

Although it won't affect performance, I would also suggest simplifying the `where` clause to:

```
where parsing_status IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I will give you some tips

### 1. Improve query

```sql
SELECT t1.purchaseNumber, t1.parsing_status, t1.docPublishDate
FROM xml_files t1
LEFT JOIN xml_files t2
  ON t1.purchaseNumber = t2.purchaseNumber
  AND t1.docPublishDate < t2.docPublishDate
WHERE t1.parsing_status IS NULL 
AND t2.parsing_status IS NULL 
AND t2.docPublishDate IS NULL
```

### 2. Improve table

You can also try adding some index, but if the table only contains these 3 columns I am not sure how much you can improve. Depending on the data distribution, for example if you know that half of parsing_status are null, you can try:

```sql
create index idx_xml_files_2 on xml_files("parsing_status", "purchaseNumber")
```